# Canvasjs Doughnut not show all labels when re-draw chart

Tags: charts, canvasjs

I have 1 Chart Doughnut . When first time . It's working show all . But I change Data call ajax and I re draw chart doughnut then It's not working show all labels . Only show labels small  . Help me Please

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         title:{
      text: "indexLabel wrap in doughnut",
        fontSize: 20,
      },
        animationEnabled: true,
      data: [
      {        
        type: "doughnut",
         startAngle: 270,
         innerRadius: 80,
        indexLabel: " #percent %",
        indexLabelFontColor : "black",
        indexLabelPlacement: "outside", 
        indexLabelWrap: true ,
        dataPoints: [
          {  y: 280, label : "some label" },          
          { y: 148,label : "other label" },
          {  y: 16, label : "some other label"},
          {  y: 32, label : "label" }  ,
           {  y: 12, label : "label" }  
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 460px; width: 460px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7709.png)

Answer (score 1):

[indexLabels](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/indexlabel/) seems to be skipped due to space constraint, i.e. as you have rotated the doughnut by setting startAngle and width is set, there is no space for indexLabel of the particular datapoint. By changing [startAngle](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/startangle/) by a few values or by increasing the width, it’s possible to display more indexLabels. Here is the updated code:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
    text: "indexLabel wrap in doughnut",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  animationEnabled: true,
  data: [
    {        
      type: "doughnut",
      startAngle: 320,
      innerRadius: 80,
      indexLabel: " #percent %",
      indexLabelFontColor : "black",
      indexLabelPlacement: "outside", 
      indexLabelWrap: true ,
      dataPoints: [
        {  y: 280, label : "some label" },          
        { y: 148,label : "other label" },
        {  y: 16, label : "some other label"},
        {  y: 32, label : "label" }  ,
        {  y: 12, label : "label" }  
      ]
    }
  ]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 460px; width: 460px;"></div>
```